# Finding the general solution for 3x3 differential equation with 1 eigenvector

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm stuck on this question of finding the general solution involves a matrix with one eigenvalue and only 2 eigenvectors. 
The matrix is 
$\begin {bmatrix}2&-1&-1\\ 0&1&-1\\ 0&1&3\end {bmatrix} = A$
with the system $\ X' = AX $ and the initial condition $ X(0) = \begin {bmatrix}1&0&1\end {bmatrix} $
I know the eigenvalue is 2 and it has 2 eigenvectors [0 -1 1] and [1 0 0]. I am trying to find the third and the general solution but not quite sure how. 
Please help thank you!

Comment: Do you know how to find eigenvalues? How about finding eigenvectors once you have eigenvalues?

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/825804/general-solution-of-a-system-of-linear-differential-equations-with-multiple-gene

Answer (score 1):

The generic approach, per [the linked question in the comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/825804/general-solution-of-a-system-of-linear-differential-equations-with-multiple-gene), would be to find a generalized eigenvector for $A$ and corresponding solution of the form $e^{2t}(v_1+tv_2)$ and then solve for an appropriate linear combination of independent solutions that satisfies the initial condition.

Since all of the eigenvalues are equal, however, this problem admits what I think is a simpler approach. Since, as you’ve already determined, the only eigenvalue is $2$ with geometric multiplicity $2$, then $(A-2I)^2=0$. Setting $N=A-2I$, this means that $$e^{tA}=e^{t(2I+N)} = e^{2t}e^{tN} = e^{2t}(I+tN) = e^{2t}\begin{bmatrix}1&-t&-t\\0&1-t&-t\\0&t&1+t\end{bmatrix}$$ and the solution to the initial value problem is $e^{tA}X(0)$, which is easily computed.